# How to change the interval for tasks.loop in discord.py during runtime

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to make a bot that reminds people to drink enough water every few hours. I tried to do this with tasks but realized that I can't let the user decide the interval since the timing for the loop already gets initialized right when you start the bot and can't be changed anymore.

I saw solutions that just used sleep instead of tasks but those blocked the bot from processing any other commands while it runs. My current solution is to have 5 different loops that can get toggled but it's in my opinion not a very great solution. This is what it looks like right now:

```
@client.command()
async def w(ctx, t = None):
    global w
    global channel
    global ti
    
    if w:
        if ti == "3":
            water3.cancel()
        elif ti == "1":
            water1.cancel()
        elif ti == "2":
            water2.cancel()
        elif ti == "4":
            water4.cancel()
        elif ti == "5":
            water5.cancel()

        w = False
        await ctx.send("The water reminder is turned off")
    else:
        channel = ctx.channel
        message = "The water reminder is turned on"
        ti = t
        w = True

        if t == None or t == "3":
            ti = 3
            water3.start()
        elif t == "1":
            water1.start()
        elif t == "2":
            water2.start()
        elif t == "4":
            water4.start()
        elif t == "5":
            water5.start()
        else:
            message = "Invalid command: Please choose a number from 1 to 5"
            w = False
        
        await ctx.send(message)


@tasks.loop(minutes = 3)
async def water3():
    await channel.send("Remember to drink water")

@tasks.loop(minutes = 1)
async def water1():
    await channel.send("Remember to drink water")

@tasks.loop(minutes = 2)
async def water2():
    await channel.send("Remember to drink water")

@tasks.loop(minutes = 4)
async def water4():
    await channel.send("Remember to drink water")

@tasks.loop(minutes = 5)
async def water5():
    await channel.send("Remember to drink water")
```

It works but I don't like it. There must be a better way to do this, right?

Comment: If I am not strongly mistaken if you use `asyncio.sleep` for such a loop it will not block your bot.

Comment: [change_interval](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval), is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Daraan Ah yes you're right asyncio.sleep itself doesn't block the bot but the while loop that I put it into so that the timer keeps repeating blocks it

Comment: @Catgal Thanks a lot. It looks like that should work